# date formatter different output on different devices running same iOS version

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

```
NSDate *currentDate =  [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy,h,mm,a"];
NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:currentDate];
[format release];

NSLog(dateString);
```

Output in: Device iPhone4 
[240:707] **10/25/2011,22,23,** 
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
warning: Unable to read symbols for /SDK4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib

Output in: Device iPad2 
[82:707] **10/25/2011,12,28,PM**
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
warning: Unable to read symbols for /SDK4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib

This thing works fine on Simulator for all.

How to handle this?

**More Info:**
it is also to notice that the same formatting string resulting in 12 hr and 24 hr clock values in return

Comment: The time may be different in the two devices.. Set Same time and time zone..Then check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally resolved it.
it was due to the settings in phone as 24 Hr clock.

I had to update my code accordingly.

:)

Comment: @Devang despite the comment and slightly confusing answer, TheEye points to the correct answer — with some locales the date formatter may selectively adjust parts of a specified date format. That's because the date formatter is really for two different things, both printing dates for people and doing unicode date formatting, and considers the former more important than the latter. Setting a locale of `en_US_POSIX` on the formatter resolves the conflict, always giving you exactly the formatting you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a different **locale** set on your iPad and your iPhone, see here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Either set the same locale on both devices (if it's just your problem) or make sure the NSDateFormatter uses the same (hard-coded) locale if you rely on the format being like a certain format.

**Edit: Additional Info**

It apparently IS a problem with the locale, more detailed here (with solutions):
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html

But I was wrong, setting the locale will not help it indeed.

Citation:

`On iPhone OS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time setting (via Settings > General > Date & Time > 24-Hour Time), which causes NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string you set, which can cause your time parsing to fail.`

Comment: setting locale does not affect the 24/12 hr clock. This is the issue I could possibly see here..!!

Comment: In contrast to samfisher's comment above, my testing showed that the locale does affect whether the date formatter decides to substitute the 12-hour clock for the 24-hour clock irrespective of an explicit date format (though it seems specifically to happen only if you override the default 12/24 clock setting in some locales). Explicitly setting a locale of en_US_POSIX as per QA1480 resolves the problem.