# Ensure AM / PM (Period) does not appear in NSDateFormat stringFromDate

Tags: ios, objective-c

The Unicode Date Format Patterns guide ([here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)) state that appending an 'a' to the format will get the period (AM or PM for instance), e.g.,

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss a"];
```

However I wish to ensure that the period information does not appear but I cannot find a format string to do that. The format string I am using is as follows:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

unfortunately, when I use stringFromDate I get the following:

**2013-01-09T11:11:00 AM**

I dont wish to simply strip AM or PM from the resultant string because the period syntax may be different in differing Calendars etc, I just want to stop the period information appearing.

----8<------

Consider the following code

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *stringDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

self.labelOutput.text = stringDate;

[formatter release];
```

This code will produce a string in the format I want - however I cannot use it for memory management reasons. The app I am working on is plagued by NSDateFormatter memory leaks. So we use a singleton class to provide a set number NSDateFormatters to the app which are never released and therefore we minimise how much memory is being leaked. Unfortunately these static NSDateFormatters are appending AM / PM even when I apply a date format string thus:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [MyDateFormatter dateFormat:kFormatDateMediumStyleTimeShortStyle];

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Odd, do you mind posting the entire method where this is happening or a more relevant snippet if the method body is too big?

Comment: It would worth showing the MyDateFormatter subclass. iE does it incorrectly overwrite `setDateFormat:` and similar methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I have settled on. It's a bit simplistic but it does the job.

```
@interface NSDateFormatter (Utils)

- (NSString *)stringWithNoPeriodInformationFromDate:(NSDate*)date;

@end

@implementation NSDateFormatter (Utils)

- (NSString *)stringWithNoPeriodInformationFromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSString *stringWithPotentialPeriodInformation = [self stringFromDate:date];
    NSString *stringWithNoAMInformation = [stringWithPotentialPeriodInformation stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[self AMSymbol] withString:@""];
    NSString *stringWithNoPeriodInformation = [stringWithNoAMInformation stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[self PMSymbol] withString:@""];

    return stringWithNoPeriodInformation;
}

@end
```

Comment: is it return currect date?? i dont think so, it is just removing `AM/PM` from date.

Answer (score 6):

According to [date formatter different output on different devices running same iOS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885742/date-formatter-different-output-on-different-devices-running-same-ios-version#comment14113662_7890224), set the local of your `NSDateFormatter` to `en_US_POSIX` will fix this.

Additional to set Local you may wish avoid problems with time zone setting it like: 
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on user's settings.

Please see [Fixed Formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13) part of Data Formatting Guide. Note this sentence:

> In iOS, **the user can override** the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time
>   setting. This may cause NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string
>   you set.

And at the end of the paragraph:

> The representation of the time may be 13:00. In iOS, however, **if the
>   user has switched 24-Hour Time to Off**, the time may be 1:00 pm.

Comment: noted, thanks: However that doesn't explain the two scenarios i have just highlighted above. The user settings have not been changed but one omits AM / PM; one doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You need to use POSIX here a sample code

```
  NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

      [rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
      [rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
      [rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

      // Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate.
      NSDate *date = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:rfc3339DateTimeString];
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create your own NSFormatter. I did that on my code when I couldn't get the formatter in Xcode's Interface Builder to do what I wanted. Granted, I was only looking for hours, minutes, and seconds and not the full date.

As for the memory leaks: if you can, use ARC. If you can't, use Xcode's Static Analyzer to try and track down improper retain counts.