# Getting different time formats on simulator and local devices - Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

Im trying to get a `String` date from `Date()` as shown below:

```
func today() -> String {
    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

But the output diverse from when I'm running it on Simulator and local device:

On local device the output - "24 Nov 2019"

On Simulator iPhone 8 the output - "Nov 24, 2019"

*When I'm using date format from template ( such as "MMMMd-yyyy" ) the result still diverse from device to simulator.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: set `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"`, it will return same output in all the platforms.

Comment: @SGDev I've tried it, the date is correct but the format I'm getting diverse, when I'm running the app on my phone I'm getting "24 Nov 2019" though the expected output should be "Nov 24, 2019"

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885742/date-formatter-different-output-on-different-devices-running-same-ios-version

Comment: The comma you get is most likely caused by the simulator using "en_US_POSIX", "en_US" or similar as the locale. You should specifically set the locale you want to use or accept that you get different formats if it is the users locale you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason you are getting different result is because the locale of your mac (Simulator) and your iPhone are different and DateFormatter depends on locale to turn date into string. when you don't give DateFormatter explicit locale it uses your device, so if you need same result, set locale.

```
func today() -> String {
    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

here's an interesting site to check different results.
https://nsdateformatter.com

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, but the issue is not the date itself, the date is correct. The format is the issue, to be more precise, the unexpected comma that I get on one device, but on other no comma :  "24 Nov 2019" and "Nov 24, 2019"

Comment: It's not "unexpected", as I said locale on your iphone differs from your mac, check the updated answer to get the same result